# How can i dynamically change the properties of a widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

For example the widget "IgnorePointer", which have a property "ignoring" that can be either true or false. but i want to change and access this property dynamically.

if the ignoring is true, then i want its child color to be different otherwise normal. and on a click of button i want to set this property true/false, help please.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HelloWorld extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_HelloWorldState createState() => _HelloWorldState();
}

class _HelloWorldState extends State<HelloWorld> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: Column(children: <Widget>[

  IgnorePointer(
      ignoring: false, //<= the property we talkin about
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text("Useless Button"),
        onPressed: () {},
      )
      ),

  FlatButton(
    child: Text("Toggle IgnorePointer"),
    onPressed: () {}, //TODO : toggle IgnorePointer's property true or false.
  )
]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just create a simple variable of type bool and set to it default value(true or false) as per your requirement and change it's value FlatButton onPressd method in setState.

It can be something look like this.

```
class HelloWorld extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HelloWorldState createState() => _HelloWorldState();
  }

  class _HelloWorldState extends State<HelloWorld> {

    bool check = false;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: Column(children: <Widget>[

            IgnorePointer(
                ignoring: check, //<= the property we talkin about
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Useless Button"),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
            ),

            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Toggle IgnorePointer"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if(check){
                    check = false;
                  }else{
                    check = true;
                  }
                });
              }, //TODO : toggle IgnorePointer's property true or false.
            )
          ]));
    }
  }
```

Comment: a small adition to your code  child: Text("Useless Button",style: TextStyle(color:check == true ? Colors.blue : Colors.green ),), as he wants to change colour on value of ignore pointer